# How often is the /etc/shadow file backed up?

Tags: linux, files, backup

From man 5 shadow:

/etc/shadow-

```
   Backup file for /etc/shadow.

   Note that this file is used by the tools of the shadow toolsuite,
   but not by all user and password management tools.
```

What I would like to know is, when this file is backed up? Is there a configuration file in which change the frequency of, or even disable, this backups?

Comment: Don't rely on it. Back-up to somewhere off site (and secure). Also consider, in addition, revision control such as `etc keeper`.

Comment: Well, I need to know this in order to conclude some things in a forensic analysis.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you change the `/etc/shadow` file with the `vipw` or similar command, it saves the previous copy as `/etc/shadow-` .  This is **not** a backup.  It's simply an instant-mistake fixer.

Answer (score 1):

It is retained as a copy of /etc/shadow and created upon changes. Nothing to configure there.